# Finding smallest String / Word

Tags: java

I am new to Java and programming in general, keep that in mind and don't be harsh on me please ^^. Next on I did some training with Java recently and I love the challenge however right now I am just stuck. I did some examples to find the largest string typed from the user and it all went fine, however now I just wanted the opposite to find the smallest one, and it just won't show it as output, it only shows blank as the result.
Here's the code:

/* Gjen fjalen me te vogel te shtypur nga user-i dhe e paraqet si rezultat se bashku me numrin total te fjaleve te shtypura */

```
import java.util.*;
public class fjalaMin {
    private static Scanner sc;
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fjalet ="";
        String fjalaMin ="";
        String SENTINEL ="FUND";
        int count = 0;

        System.out.println("Shtypni fjalet e deshiruara ose shtypni ' FUND ' per te terminuar programin: ");
        do {
            fjalet = sc.nextLine();
            if(fjalet.equalsIgnoreCase(SENTINEL)) {
                break;
            } else if(fjalet.length() < fjalaMin.length()) {
                fjalaMin = fjalet;
            }

            count++;
        }
        while(!fjalet.equalsIgnoreCase(SENTINEL));

        if(count == 0) {
            System.out.println("Nuk keni shtypur asnje fjale!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Rezultati juaj: ");
            System.out.println("Numri total i fjaleve te shtypura: " + count);
            System.out.println("Fjala me e shkurte qe eshte shtypur eshte: " + fjalaMin);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your input?...  Also add additional logs in the `do`block

Comment: I understand that logically nothing is smaller than nothing (the start value of fjalaMin is blank... however how do I go around this? What other value can I give it to make it work?)

Thanks in advance and I can translate this to english if you guys are confused.

Comment: I removed my comment and intended to write an answer but was beaten by kai. Have a look at his proposal as this is probably what you need.

Comment: Btw, you should start class names with a capital letter. This is "just" a convention but will make things easier, i.e. `fjalaMin` occurs twice in your code: once as class name and once as variable name in the main method. Besides the naming itself, which I can't comment on because I don't understand the language, this is considered bad design.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you very much for the feedback, even though I am a beginner I can honestly understand your point clearly and I did actually think about it, if the class name is used somewhere else, would it cause confusion later on. Your tip might just save me in the future. Thank you and yes Kai's solution worked flawlessly. Thanks again for your tip.

Comment: You're welcome. As long as people put some effort into their questions (e.g. show what they tried and that they already did some research) all are welcome whether they are beginners or not. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you initialize `String fjalaMin = "";` with an empty String, so no string is shorter. You can initialize it with a long String or if you want to be safe you can initialize it with `null` and change your condition to:

```
else if (fjalaMin == null || fjalet.length() < fjalaMin.length())
{
    fjalaMin = fjalet; // always the first input will be stored
}
```

Now it should work fine.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the reply to all of you, this might be embarrasing to be asked but I'm just new, I mean I tried to give the value of null to fjalaMin but then it just gave me some error cause I guess I did not include the result being null as an option at the ' else if ' condition. So you saved me @kai Thanks again to all of you.

Peace <3